# How do I add >100 new rows to a SQLite DB in the documents directory without overwriting?

Tags: xcode, sqlite, xcode4.3

I have a SQLite table that I'm using for my iPad app. It currently has about 500 items, but I need to add about 200+ more. The thing is, the app is already deployed and has users, and it's an editable database in the documents directory, so it's not like I can just overwrite it. How can I add these new rows easily without destroying the table that I already have? It would be nice to import a txt somehow without having to do this manually. (For the record I am not using Core Data.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throwing out some ideas:

Can you not deploy a new database file in your update, and programatically detect if there is an existing db.  If so, add the new data to the database and if not create a new db programatically, and add all your data to it.

You could store the setup data in an xml file perhaps?

ALTERNATELY, could your update have a second database?  You don't overwrite your original db and you add a v1.1 db file?  You could then merge the v1.1 data into the original db?

Comment: Sounds good, I can use the SELECT INTO statement that I didn't know existed until just now. Thanks for the help!